# VMDK to ISO file converter

Tags: iso, vmdk

I am using virtualbox and creating a VMDK file.
I am creating ova file using virtualbox. but there is no any option to create iso file.Please suggest how I am convert this VMDK to ISO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly follow this url - https://www.sevenbits.io/blog/iso/puredarwin/osx/2015/03/11/convert-to-iso.html

It works for me.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: The link is archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20201210065809/https://www.sevenbits.io/blog/iso/puredarwin/osx/2015/03/11/convert-to-iso.html. 

In effect: `qemu-img convert -f vmdk filename.vmdk pd.raw` then `dd if=pd.raw of=pd.iso`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert .vmdk filed p.e. on Ubuntu Linux Komsole on follow way:

```
qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O raw your_source_file.vmdk your_destination_file.img
```

Thats works fine for MBR a dont work for GPT.